# ASP NET CORE долгие запросы API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Как выполнять долгие запросы к API? В планировщике задач есть задача которая выполняется раз в сутки(запрос по uri api). При переходе на этот uri сервер начинает обновлять данные в бд(примерно 10сек на один не изменённый элемент(не надо перезаписывать), таких элементов примерно 30, но со временем их количество будет увеличиваться). После ~120 секунд все перестает работать и в ответе планировщика из-за долгого времени ожидания.

Comment: делать эту работу в бекграунде. HTTP API не предназначен для долгих запросов.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: aepot, я примерно понял, что вы предлагаете, но пока что не реализовал т.к. не до конца понял как. Правильнее делать это через через Polly или signalR?

Comment: Я не знаю, я реализовывал HTTP, но на более низком уровне, как бы в курсе, что там внутри, но именно с использованием ASP.NET Core не пробовал, тем более у вас требование весьма специфичное. Мой ответ описывает только некую абстрактную логику очевидного мне, вменяемого способа реализации, а уж какой код для этого надо писать и какие именно инструменты брать - точно не подскажу. Знаю только что Polly и SignalR - совешенно про разное и не имеют ничего общего. Здесь зависит от того, какой подходк к решению вы выберете как разработчик. Вариантов, как я и указывал, несколько, и все рабочие.

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его, не обязательно ждать, когда вы выпустите свой проект в релиз. :) Если у вас появится другой вопрос, вы всегда сможете задать его отдельно. Главная суть: есть поллинг, и есть вебсокет, при наличии вебсокета, поллинг не нужен, ну просто смысла в нем нет. С точки зрения сетевой эффективности, вебсокет лучше, так как запросов меньше, трафика меньше. Других разниц не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через заголовок HTTP retry-after общаться с клиентом, чтобы он выполнял поллинг статуса запроса через какой-то нужный серверу промежуток времени. А отвечать на то что данные приняты надо сразу, и не ждать когда они будут полностью обработаны.

К примеру клиенту можно вернуть что-то типа

```json
{
    "QueryId" : 12345,
    "Message": "Запрос принят."
}
```

Далее клиент делает запрос в `/queryStatus/12345` и получает ответ

```json
{
    "Status": "Pending",
    "Message": "Выполняется...",
    "Progress": 0.35
}
```

И уже в ответе пусть будет заголовок `retry-after` со значением времени, через какой промежуток запрос следует повторить. Клиент может подчиниться, может нет, но это хороший инструмент регулировать периодичность запросов от "честных" клиентов со стороны сервера, чтобы не перенагружать его.

Клиент повторяет запрос несколько раз и потом получает ответ

```json
{
    "Status": "Success",
    "Message": "Запрос выполнен.",
    "Progress": 1
}
```

Или

```json
{
    "Status": "Error",
    "Message": "Ошибка при запросе.",
    "Progress": 0
}
```

Здесь есть вопросы типа "сколько времени хранить данные о результатах запроса?", но это решаемо.

Само собой это только рекомендация реализации в рамках Web API. Но я бы пошел копать в сторону WebSocket/SignalR, чтобы держать постоянную двухстороннюю связь с клиентом, тогда ему вообще не приходилось заниматься поллингом.